# How accurate is it to use 12-6 LJ potential for interaction between nano-particle and Hydrogen molecule in LAMMPS?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, nanoscience

I am trying to simulate a large system containing nano particles (that are fixed in space) and gas molecules passing through the void space between nano particles using LAMMPS. The nano particles have been approximated as hard spheres.

How accurate would it be to use the basic 12-6 LJ potential for the interaction between nanoparticles and the gas molecules?

Comment: 12-6 LJ potential? That is the terminology used for a particular variant of LJ where 12 and 6 represent the powers of the distance variable. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lennard-Jones_potential)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

obviously that depends and what you mean by accurate.

Generally, if your gas molecules are non-polar simple molecules, like, e.g.
methane, you should be fine either way. If your molecules are polar AND your nano 
particles have a polar surface, then using a simple LJ or hard sphere potential might
give a poor representation of the true system.

If you meant to say: how similar will the results using the LJ potential
be to those I'd get using hard spheres? then you should be able to get
reasonably close.

If you write the LJ potential in the form:
$U(r) = 4 \epsilon \left\{\left(\frac{\sigma}{r}\right)^{12}-\left(\frac{\sigma}{r}\right)^6\right\}$
then you can always make sigma small (and epsilon large) so that the resulting
interaction is very close to a hard sphere potential.
However (depending on your temperature) the steeper (the more hard sphere like) the 
potential, the shorter the time-step you need to use, increasing the required computational resources. So its a trade off: to more faithful you reproduce the hard 
sphere interactions the more expensive (in terms of required CPU time) your 
simulations will be.

In any case, if you choose your epsilon/sigma so that the width of the
LJ potential is small compared to the smallest distance between your nano particles 
(you can establish that by simple visial inspection, looking at the potential in, 
e.g., gnuplot or excel) you should be fine.

This being said, if the size difference between your nano-particle and the gas 
molecules is substantial, and you work at low gas densities your simulations
might be considerably more efficient (again in terms of the required CPU time)
if you use some kind of event driven MD code (just google).

cheers
michael